# How to refresh page with data received from another post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making test ecommerce website with a Nodejs server.
When User press Buy Button, I create a JSON and post request to Payment Server.
Then Payment server response with QRcode string.
I display this QRcode to user and ask for making payment by scanning this QRcode with their payment APP.
User scan the QRcode and made payment.
Payment server then send my server that payment was success.
I response to payment server that I receive this.

Then my question is how do I show "Payment is Successful." Message to user when user successfully finished payment?

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sha256 = require('sha256');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require("request");
const QRCode = require('qrcode');
const replace = require('replace-in-file');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.enable('trust proxy');

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  // send page with Buy Button
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
})

// User made post req by clicking Buy Button
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var product
  var orderID
  var topaymentjson = {"product" : product, "orderID" : orderID, "notifyurl" : "https://myserver.com/notifyurl"}
  var url = "https://api.payment.com/api_url"

  request({
         url: url,
         method: "POST",
         json: topaymentjson
     }, function (error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
             console.log(body)

              QRCode.toDataURL(body.Response.qrCode, function (err, url) {
              res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
              var beforecode = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" dir="ltr"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title></title> </head> <body> <img src="'
              var aftercode = '" alt=""> </body> </html>'
              // ask user to scan this qrcode and make payment
              res.write(beforecode + url + aftercode);
              // How do I refresh this page with PAYMENT SUCCESS message to user only after
              // my notifyurl receive post request with {"orderID" : "12345", "status" : "PAYMENTSUCCESS"}

              res.end();
              })
         }
         else {
             console.log("error: " + error)
         }
 })
});

// When user payment finished, the payment server make post request to this url with
// JSON {"orderID" : "12345", "status" : "PAYMENTSUCCESS"}
app.post('/notifyurl', function (req, res) {
  if (req.body.orderID == orderID && req.body.status == "PAYMENTSUCCESS") {
    // How to pass data to user post request and refresh user page?
  }
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('success');

});

const port =2000;
app.listen(port,()=>{
console.log(`App running on ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: You can either use a polling technique or websockets. I prefer websockets but it's more complex.

Comment: Is there any simple solution? How about promise, or observable?

Comment: There are 3 systems involved: the client, the website server and the payment server. You want to send an update from website server to client after the payment server sent a confirmation to the website server. You can't send from website server to client with HTTP. You can either poll from the client or send through websocket.

Comment: You can solve the problem with promises using https://www.meteor.com/. It will create the websockets under the hood for you. But probably you have to restructure much of the project.